# How to exclude nodes with a taxonomy term from XML Sitemap?

Tags: xml-sitemap

We can exclude content type, or individual node from [XML Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap). But, is there anyway to exclude nodes with specific taxonomy term? For example excluding nodes with `longlivethetroll` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_xmlsitemap_element_alter() to check if the node has a particular taxonomy term & exclude it.

```
function MYMODULE_xmlsitemap_element_alter(&$element, $link, $sitemap) {
  // Check if link is a node link
  if ($link['type'] == 'node') {
    $node = node_load($link['id']);

    // Code to check if $node has taxonomy term goes here
    if ($node has taxonomy term) {
      $element['disabled'] = TRUE; // This removes the node link from sitemap
    }
  }
}
```